# Webkit Render Issue with changing text

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, hover, gradient

Alright, so I asked a question a while ago, and I was told to use CSS to change my gradients, so I did, and it worked, kind of. It seems to be a webkit render issue, I asked in chat, and we both had the same problem, with my version of safari (Version 6.0 (8536.25) and his version (Version 5.1.7 (6534.57.2))

[image: Web Render Error?]

Here is my jsfiddle code; http://jsfiddle.net/Fluffy977/ZauwA/ | Without text styling and gradients: http://jsfiddle.net/Fluffy977/YXD5m/

Comment: Just to let you know, IE9 doesn't render that button.

Comment: I am aware, only webkit browsers will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works: http://jsfiddle.net/ZauwA/30/

#### Edit

After you settled with the Javascript, use this great tool for designing the gradient:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

#### Edit

A bit about [Jquery](http://jquery.com):

[Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/): `$('#home, #home a')` makes Jquery selects 2 kinds of elements: the one with `id=home` and the `A` elements that are descendant from the one with `id=home`. Since I used a comma, this makes more that one selector being applied to the document.

Then we have the [event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/): for `click`, `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

You can see that each one was applied one right after another, this is called [chaining](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/quick-guide-chaining-in-jquery/). Since almost every Jquery method returns the Jquery object itself, this makes code compact.

In each event handler, I used the `css` function to apply a style to the elements, then the `html` function (it's the same thing as setting `innerHTML`).

(And everything listening to this soundtrack :D http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69xSV0oZYpE&feature=autoplay&list=UU-ilGJ5YU9bt4yA7lnYq9nw&playnext=2)

Comment: Thanks for the tool, can you comment that code, I understand little of it, (newb at Javascript)

Comment: Issue is still present in recent Safari versions, and the fiddle was due some time ago. Could you add to the answer the [portion of] snippet to make this work? If you may also add why is this happening would be nice :)

Comment: How embarassing, the jsfiddle pages were deleted... I suggest you ask this in a new question, and create an example using the HTML/JS/CSS code embedded in SO.